# How to modify wordpress plugin functions without editing the plugin?

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins

I'm working with wordpress and I search to modify plugin functions without editing the plugin **for not break function after update**.

But I didn't find solution yet. Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please specify **which** plugin you want to modify? Unfortunately most plugins are not written in a way that allows overwriting of their functionality without modifying their code, but IF you are lucky the plugin you want to edit might be one that will let you do that using hooks and filters.

Comment: I would like modify the WPML plugin. but do_action() hooks aren't present in most of the functions this plugin

Comment: if it is a class, you can TRY to extend the class..

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I'll try to extend the WPML class.

Comment: But is it possible to overwrite a php function class ?

Comment: You can't overwrite PHP functions - you can only overwrite class methods(functions belonging to a class), by extending the original class and defining those functions in your class. 
The problem extending the WPML class would be to see if you can actually use your class instead of the WPML one(I presume that they are using their own class for function callbacks). See if they make a global variable - similar to `$wpml = new WMPL();` - if they do, see if you can access it. If you can, you'll be able to overwrite that.

Comment: I'll try it tonight. I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: Further to @NikolaIvanovNikolov you can use remove action if the plugin class uses add_action. You still need the global variable for the class. It's best practice for plugin developers to use a global variable for this reason, but sadly not all do.

Comment: @Mark - yeah that's true. Quite recently I had to manually go through the `$wp_filter` global variable in order to remove two callbacks for an action set-up by a plugin. The problem was that the class object wasn't available in any way(`$this` was always used and there was no global variable pointing to the object), so that was my only solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue many times. As others have said, you cannot modify PHP functions. Extending the class will not work because the plugin will instantiate the original class, not your extended version.

The best solution (has worked for me several times) is to add hooks to the existing plugin and submit back to the original author as follows:

1. If the original plugin is on github, fork and clone it. Otherwise, put the original plugin under `git` control locally. You may need to do a diff or rollback later.
2. Create a new plugin called WPML-extensions (or something)
3. Search the original plugin code for actions or filters to use. If they are already available and do what you need, use them by hooking to them from the WPML-extensions plugin.
4. If the correct hooks are not present in the WPML plugin, add them and then follow the step above. Try to use the latest version of the original plugin to maximize your chances of your changes being accepted.
5. If you have modified the original plugin by adding actions or filters, do a `git diff` to save the patch so you can re-apply it later. Submit the patch to the original plugin author and hope for the best. If you stuck with just actions and filters, the author will most likely accept your changes immediately.
6. If you update the original plugin later, you need to re-apply your changes until they are accepted. You can use that diff file. There may be a way to use `git rebase` to replay the changes you made after updating the plugin.